# Angular dynamic component animation leave doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

Let's say I have the following component that I created dynamically.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <template #alertContainer></template>
    <button (click)="clear()">clear</button>
    <button (click)="createComponent('success')">Create success alert</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
 @ViewChild("alertContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;
 componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  clear() {
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }

  createComponent(type) {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AlertComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

And the AlertComponent:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <section [@fadeInOut]>
     <h1>Alert</h1>
    <section>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(500, style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(500, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])
  ],
})
export class AlertComponent {

}
```

When I create the component the animation works and I get the expected fade in effect. When I click on the clear button which destroys the component I doesn't get any animation effect. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating and destroying the component manually instead of letting the angular framework handle that and thus it's animations. You don't get a leave animation because you destroy (it's gone) the component.

**edit**

Instead of destroying your component immediately, you can have to clear function trigger the leave animation and use a callback `(@fadeInOut.done)="animationDone($event)"` to destroy the component.

Comment: Ofcourse it works when entering. You create it, so it exists to animate. When you remove something from existence, it cannot animate because it isn't there.

Comment: Which version of angular are you on?

Comment: I'm in version 5.2.

Comment: 'Of course it works when entering'. Honestly I'm slightly surprised it does. I would have thought some relevant framework logic wasn't going to get 'hit' when you did it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You bound your animation on the `section` tag, not the component host itself. thus your animation triggers when fading in. they both (`component` and `section`) are instantiated together. but when you destroy your component, the `section` tag is destroyed with it, and animation doesn't work (animation on `section` will work only if the tag destroys directly). you destroy its parent. try to bind animation on the component host itself using @Hostbinding decorator or destroy the `section` itself and after the animation, do destroy the component using `animation end` event.